# How can I make monit poll more often during a state change?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I'm using Monit to monitor various processes that need to be up and running *as a group* for a web site to work properly. To bring up or bring down the site, there's a definite order by which the processes must be started or stopped. The dependencies are as follows. (The names have been changed to protect the innocent. I use more descriptive names in the real configuration.)

1. The service `site` depends on `site.workerA`, `site.workerB` and `site-redis`.
2. Both workers depend on `site-redis`.

The site is always started or stopped through Monit so as to avoid the possibility of race conditions, or Monit working against me. (e.g. I stop a service and Monit keeps starting it back.)

The problem is that it takes much more time than necessary to bring the whole site up. If I instruct Monit to start the site, then once Monit has figured the dependencies, the sequence of actions on Monit's part is:

1. Starts `site-redis`.
2. Sleeps for 2 minutes.
3. Detects that `site-redis` is running, so start the two workers.
4. Sleeps for 2 minutes.
5. Detects that the workers and redis are running, so start `site`.
6. [Sleeps for 2 minutes]
7. [Detects that `site` is running.]

I've bracketed the last 2 steps because they are practically moot since the site is effectively up and running before the last 2 minute interval.

The 2 minute sleep is the default polling interval that Monit uses to check on services. I know that I could reduce this interval so that these services are *always* polled more frequently. For instance, I could do

```
check process site.workerB pidfile "/srv/site/var/run/site/site.workerB.pid"
    every [number] cycles
    ...
```

I would also have to change the length of the polling cycle to something smaller so that a cycle is less than 2 minutes.

However, I don't want Monit to *always* poll these services more frequently. **I'd like Monit to only poll services more frequently when it is in the midst of waiting for a state change.** Say, if Monit has started a service and another service depends on it, poll at a 5 second interval rather than 2 minutes.

I'm not seeing any way to configure Monit to do this, but maybe I missed something.

---

Here is an illustration of my prose description above. After removing things that are not pertinent to the issue, the Monit configuration is like this:

```
check process site-redis pidfile ".../site/redis.pid"
      group site
      start program = ...
      stop program = ...
      if does not exist then start

check process site pidfile ".../site/site.pid"
      group site
      depends on site.workerA, site.workerB, site-redis
      start program = ...
      stop program = ...
      if does not exist then start

check process site.workerA pidfile ".../site/site.workerA.pid"
      group site
      depends on site-redis
      start program = ...
      stop program = ...
      if does not exist then start

check process site.workerB pidfile ".../site/site.workerB.pid"
      group site
      depends on site-redis
      start program = ...
      stop program = ...
      if does not exist then start
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in Monit (yet) best is to ask on user group mailing list (monit-general@nongnu.org) or request a new feature on the Bitbucket tracker https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually trigger a re-evaluation of monit by [`monit validate`](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#validate) or [`SIGUSR1`](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SIGNALS).

So you can rewrite your start/stop programs to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function background {
    i="0"
    while [ $i -lt 20 ]; do
        monit validate > /dev/null
        monit status __YOUR__SERVICE__NAME__HERE__ | grep OK > /dev/null && exit 0
        sleep 5
        i=$[$i+1]
    done
}


# restart procedure


state=$?

background &

exit $state
```

Long story short: After the restart procedure is completed its exit code gets tracked and a background loop is started. It runs for 20 times and sleeps for 5 seconds after each run (~ 1m40s). It forces monit to re-evaluate its state and breaks out of the loop if the state is `OK`. If not, the loop continues. Finally the script itself exits with the restart procedures exit code.